# module object access to "global" values in Jupyter notebook cell

Tags: python, module, scope, jupyter-notebook

[image: screenshot of module and notebook]I am developing an application and, for the first version, I am using a Jupyter notebook as the end-user interface. The second cell in the notebook imports all object(s) from a module that I wrote . The third cell acts like a configuration file; the end-user is expected to set variable values. In subsequent cells, module functions and/or instance methods are called, but are unable to "find" variables that were bound in the "configuration" cell.

How can I access variables like `a` in module function calls?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have much experience on python development, right? So you must understand that the variables defined in "configuration" cell are bound to current scope. They are surely global variables, but "global" is relative.

I understand what you want to do. You want to define something like a built-in one. It can be accessed in every corner without any special code such as "import".

It isn't a good practice as it will break python's scope manage strategy. What much better is you can pass arguments to that function.

If you really want to do that, you need to bind your "gloabl"(even beyond normal gloabl) variables to `__builtins__`. For example:

```
# a.py
import b
__builtins__.a = 5
b.test()

# b.py
def test():
    print(a)
```

It can work.

Comment: While I do understand Python's scoping rules at a high level, I was not sure how they interacted with Jupyter notebook cells.

Comment: Jupyter notebook is almost the same as an interactive shell in terminal. There isn't anything magic in it.